# How to highlight same words in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

As title, how to highlight same words like this:

[image]

my OS is windows.  whenever my cursor point to a words and the same words don't highlight like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ctrl+D you can select the instances of a word and even edit them at the same time
for hilighting you can use double-click, for more advance solution you can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cliffordfajardo.hightlight-selections-vscode

Comment: sorry, I mean when I click two times I hope all the same words can be highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Command+Shift+L` on Mac or `Ctrl+Shift+L` on Windows to select all similar words.